# Export products by category name instead of category id

Tags: magento-1.9, export

How can I export products by category name instead of category id?

[image]

Comment: http://magentoworks.net/importexport-magento-category-extension/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::app();
$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect('category_name');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);//optional for only enabled products
$products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);//optional for products only visible in catalog and search
$fp = fopen('exports.csv', 'w');
$csvHeader = array("sku", "category_name");
fputcsv( $fp, $csvHeader,",");
foreach ($products as $product){
    $sku = $product->getSku();
    $categoryIds = implode('|', $product->getCategoryIds());//change the category separator if needed
    $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryIds);
    $categoryData = $_category->getName();
    fputcsv($fp, array($sku, $categoryData), ",");
}
fclose($fp);
```

Put these code in root file and then run in browser it will create a csv file with category name

[image]

Comment: let me check...

Comment: If i export product by Dataflow i get product category like id, so i need to get by category name, because of i need to import.

Comment: there only i get by category name, because its easily to import

Comment: and your code not working

Comment: I tested for my magento it is working for your's i don't know. I am able to get category name in my csv file.

Comment: bro, i want to get category name at dataflow export file,

Comment: then only i can import by dataflow import

Comment: @Arjun : above code completely error

Answer (score 0):

I have build appropriate logic in my existing project,
Need to some ractify in code.

```
  public function _getCsvHeaders()
{
     $_columns = array(
         "type_id",
         "sku",
         "category_names", 
         "name",
         "url",
         "desc",
         "price",
         "images",
         "department",
         "xr_product_images",
         "description",
         "short_description",
    );
    return $_columns;
}
```

AND

```
public function exportproductbyCategoryName($categoryName = null , $limit = 100)
{
    try
    {
        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                            ->getCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('gt' => 0))
                            ->setPageSize($limit)
                            ->setCurPage(1)
                            ->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC')
                           ;
        $io = new Varien_Io_File();
        $path = Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'producttypeexport' . DS;
        $name = 'product-bussinesstype-'.$bussinessType.'.csv';
        $file = $path .   $name;
        $io->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
        $io->open(array('path' => $path));
        $io->streamOpen($file, 'w+');
        $io->streamLock(true);
        $io->streamWriteCsv($this->_getCsvHeaders());
        $headerData = array();
        $importData = 0;
        $columns = $this->_getCsvHeaders();
        foreach($products as $product)
        {
          $Prduct = mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getEntityid());
          $prod = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getProduct($Prduct->getEntityId(), null, null);
          $attributes = $prod->getTypeInstance(true)->getSetAttributes($prod);
          $galleryData = $prod->getData('media_gallery');
          $categoryIds = $Prduct->getCategoryIds();
          $names = array();
          foreach($categoryIds as $categoryId)
          {
             $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
             $names[] = $category->getName(); 
          }
          $categorynames = json_encode($names);                
          $CsvData = array();
          foreach($columns as $column)
          {
             if($column == 'category_names')
             {
                $CsvData[] = $categorynames;
                continue;  
             }
             $CsvData[] = $Prduct->getData($column);
          }
          $io->streamWriteCsv($CsvData);
          $importData++;
          continue;
        }
        return $file;
    }
    catch(Exceptin $e)
    {
        return $e->getMessage();;
    }
}
```